# how can i fix error react-scripts start. react npm start gets this error after import ml5

Tags: node.js, reactjs, p5.js

my project including p5.js was working totally well,I installed ml5 and my project was steal working well,then when I imported ml5.js in a component , got following error.
 how can I fix this error?

```
npm ERR! e-posture@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 134
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the e-posture@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\alishahi\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-01-26T07_54_07_158Z-debug.log
```

I searched and found my react-scripts version might not be compatible,but I don't know how to fix it. this my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "e-posture",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.8.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "ml5": "^0.4.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.1",
    "p5": "^0.10.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.3.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: use import * as ml5 from "ml5";

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with two steps:
1) remove ml5@0.4.3 and install ml5@0.3.1
2) import ml5 before p5 in the omponent
just these !!!